# Output size in procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, zend-framework, plsql, zend-framework2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have my procedure:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE wypiszZamienniki (z_bloz12 IN NUMBER ,output OUT VARCHAR2)
as
LV_TEST_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
IF (z_bloz12 IS NOT NULL) THEN
FOR CUR_VAR IN (SELECT p.* 
            FROM produkt p join produkt p2 on p.nazwa_miedz = p2.nazwa_miedz
            and (p.dawka_l_p like p2.dawka_l_p or
                 p.dawka_l_p is NULL and p2.dawka_l_p is NULL)
            and (p.dawka_j_p = p2.dawka_j_p or
                 p.dawka_j_p is NULL and p2.dawka_j_p is NULL)
            and (p.dawka_l_n = p2.dawka_l_n or
                 p.dawka_l_n is NULL and p2.dawka_l_n is NULL)
            and (p.dawka_j_n = p2.dawka_j_n or
                 p.dawka_j_n is NULL and p2.dawka_j_n is NULL)
            WHERE p.bloz12 != z_bloz12
            AND p2.bloz12 = z_bloz12)
  LOOP
  output := output ||CUR_VAR.nazwa || ' ' || CUR_VAR.opakowanie || ' ' || CUR_VAR.podmiot_odp;
  dbms_output.put_line(CUR_VAR.nazwa || ' ' || CUR_VAR.opakowanie || ' ' || CUR_VAR.podmiot_odp);
  end LOOP;
END IF;
END wypiszZamienniki;
```

After executing it I get

> ```
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512
> ```

Problem is that output is too short. Is it any way or trick to extend size of output? I have tried to set output value to 'short' and it works, but if I add there more characters it throws an exception.

This procedure is invoked from ZEND Framework (PHP). Code snippet from controller class:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();

$sql = 'call wypiszZamienniki( :in_param1, :get_param1)';
$parameters = array(':in_param1' => 232440132296, ':get_param1' => '');

$returndata = null;
$statement = $db->query($sql, $parameters);
$statement->bindParam(':get_param1', $returndata, PDO::PARAM_INT, 2000);
$result = $statement->execute();


Zend_Debug::dump($returndata);
$this->view->zamienniki = $returndata;
```

---

As You mentioned I cant retrive such big values from procedure so i have created function to return CURSOR:

```
create or replace 
function wypiszZam (z_bloz12 IN NUMBER) return sys_refcursor
as
   my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    if (Z_BLOZ12 is not null) then
    OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT p.* 
            FROM produkt p join produkt p2 on p.nazwa_miedz = p2.nazwa_miedz
            and (p.dawka_l_p like p2.dawka_l_p or
                 p.dawka_l_p is NULL and p2.dawka_l_p is NULL)
            and (p.dawka_j_p = p2.dawka_j_p or
                 p.dawka_j_p is NULL and p2.dawka_j_p is NULL)
            and (p.dawka_l_n = p2.dawka_l_n or
                 p.dawka_l_n is NULL and p2.dawka_l_n is NULL)
            and (p.dawka_j_n = p2.dawka_j_n or
                 p.dawka_j_n is NULL and p2.dawka_j_n is NULL)
            WHERE p.bloz12 != z_bloz12
            and P2.BLOZ12 = Z_BLOZ12;
  return my_cursor;
END IF;

END wypiszZam;
```

I also found a code that retrives cursor from called procedure. Problem is that i cant find the way to get cursor from sql query. I have to do something like this:

```
declare
V_RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
V_RETURN := WYPISZZAM(232440132296);

end;
```

Is there any way to test this from sql developer?

Comment: The size is limited to 32K.  You need to show the host code that calls this procedure.

Comment: Change the fourth parameter to bindParam from 2000 to 32000 and see if that helps.